# Oracle database 18c – ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

I have installed Oracle 18c in my local machine and i have created a user names as

```
USER_NAME := c##scott
Passkey : oracle
```

When i used to connect to that user using cmd. The following error is populating out.

```
Command: sqlplus c##scott/oracle@agndev

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

After checking the listener error I have rechecked my listener file

Listener File:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\ora_base)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\ora_base\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = AGNDEV))
    )
  )
```

Tnsnames.ora file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\ora_base\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = CLRExtProc)
          (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
      )

    AGNDEV =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = AGNDEV)
        )

  )
```

I am new to 18c can anyone say the solution to this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly says there is no listener listening on the requested address.

Check if it is running (`lsnrctl status`), and start it if necessary (`lsnrctl start`). On Windows you will need to do this in a command prompt started with administrator privileges, because it also start a Windows service. Or you can start the Windows service called something similar to `OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have checked the status by using "lsnrctl status"  and its running now and the next step when i tried to connect to the database the below error is displaying over there. 
                                                                                                                       
  ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: you should open a new question, this isa different error. Or youcheck the manual https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/ORA-12500.html#GUID-BD6AAC21-3F15-4F70-B3C5-064ADCF5EC51

Comment: Re: the ORA-12514, on the db server execute 'lsnrctl status' and see what services the listener DOES know about.  Your tns names specifics SERVICE_NAME=AGNDEV, but the error means the listener doesn't know about AGNDEV.  I'll bet your database hasn't started and registered itself with the listener.  How did you create your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files?  Your listener.ora entry "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = AGNDEV))" is rather unusual.

Answer (score -1):

You have the wrong value set for the parameter `KEY` in your `listener.ora` file. It should be `EXTPROC1521` as below:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: For different listeners on a server you have to use different strings, but it does not matter which string you use.